# How do you use VBA to check if an OLEDB provider is installed?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I've got an Excel workbook that uses the OraOLEDB.Oracle provider to update various tables from an Oracle database. It's likely that the book will be distributed to people who don't have the Oracle drivers installed. How can I check in VBA whether the provider is installed so that I can provide a graceful error message to people who try to update without the driver?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3092441/2497152

Comment: Probably more like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/165044/1188513

Comment: Do you mean OLEDB data-source or driver?

Comment: The driver. Refreshing the table results in an error if I don't have the Oracle Data Access Components installed.

Comment: I checked documentation but couldn't find anything useful. You could check error message in different conditions (driver not installed, wrong credentials, no network access of the pc...) to see if you can use that for identifying mixing driver. If yes, simply use `On Error` to catch it and display proper message.

Answer (score 0):

I'm considering this an interim answer, since I don't have a way to test it. But I found an old post (really old) [here](https://www.excelforum.com/excel-programming-vba-macros/473094-check-for-ole-db-provider.html) basically saying to test for error 3706. I don't know if that's a current error number for my particular error, but doing the following should work in any case:

```
On Error Resume Next
Application.RefreshAll
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    MsgBox "Need to install driver"
    Err.Clear
Else
    <Process data assuming successful refresh>
End If    
On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: This code may only prompt that the driver is not available but your need is different,, is to check whether OLEDB provider is installed  or not in that case this will hardly work,,, please [edit] your post & add the required VBA code, will help the community !!